# How to shift up rows where the rows are deleted in sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am working on rails and I want to up shift the rows when I delete the rows so the id of the table is consistent and there is no gap. I am using postgresql.
Can anyone tell me how to do so?

Comment: This is an uncommon request for SQL.  Can you explain why you have this requirement?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.